# ZK setText or setValue on Span or in Javascript missing ID

Tags: html, zk

Hi guys i am new to ZK framework i have some dynamic Text from a compute in the DB only a number i have create a span element in my zul everything is all right so far but when i try to change the text on the span element through Javascript the ZK engine is generating a ID for the span every time unable me to set the value using javascript and span object have neither setValue or setText or setContent please help. how can i set the value on the span? thanks a lot a god bless.

Comment: I tried to edit that, but I'm not even sure of the question you're asking there... If anything, ZK-elements will accept the good old "id" attribute, and you can define it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do here.

First, you should know that ZK is designed for the developer to work more in Java than in JavaScript. Unless it's something simple and dynamic that should really remain just on the client, you'd be best to work *within* the framework, not *against* it, and handle things like this on the server side.

Regarding the `span` component specifically, it's implementation in ZK is intended as a wrapper. In ZUL, of course, you can wrap text freely like so:

```
<span>
    Hello World!
</span>
```

However, more standard ZK would look like:

```
<label value="Hello World!" />
```

Working with a `label` component, you'll find both [Java APIs](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Label.html#setValue%28java.lang.String%29) and [JavaScript APIs](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/zul/wgt/Label.html#setValue%28_global_.String%29) for setting the value.

Finally, regarding getting JavaScript references to components, the recommended approach is [documented here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Client_Side_Programming#How_to_Get_Widget_Reference_in_JavaScript). ZK generates ids for the DOM, yup, but using their JavaScript APIs you can access widgets by the id you give widgets in Java or ZUL:

```
zk.Widget.$(jq('$mylabel')[0]).setValue('Hello World!');"
```

However, again, consider tackling this problem on the server side before trying to solve it on the client side. Not knowing much about what you need to do exactly, if you are going to the database, it'll probably be more clean and efficient to set this label's text from the server anyway.